# ApplicationSignInManager class is null during authentication process

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

The following code is being used in ASP.NET MVC 5 project. Everytime I run the following code the ApplicationSignInManager Class always comes to be null causing null reference exception. Being fairly a newbie I don't understand what code calls in the constructor of AccountController class passing in the instance of usermanager and sign in manager. perhaps that is where I need to focus but the truth is I can't find that part of the code. Anyone up for help?

To be precise the exception is thrown from the HTTPost login method. The signInManager is always null.

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password,
                                     model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

Below is the c sharp code

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }


    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set { _signInManager = value; }
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
 }
```

Code from IdentityConfig.

```
// Configure the application sign-in manager which is used in this application.
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does you Auth.Config.cs (or however it is called in your project - the file which sets all the Identity stuff) look like?

Comment: Do you mean Identity.Config?

Comment: Maybe - there should be something like `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);` in there...

Comment: I have added the code from identifyconfig which sets the signinmanager

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you ever find out what was the cause of it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check for the following inside your `Identity.Config.cs`:

```
public static void RegisterAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // other code
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
    // other code
}
```

and somewhere in your project (possibly `Startup.cs`)

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup), "Configuration")]    
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In MVC5, the block to specify creation per Owin context may live in `Startup.Auth.cs` instead of `IdentityConfig.cs` (at least, with a new MVC5 + Web API project).

Answer (score 1):

if that variable is always nulla maybe there is a problem with

```
public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set { _signInManager = value; }
    }
```

the first ime `_signInManager` is null so if  `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>()` returns null your property will be null and you'll get that error.

Check what `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>()` returns and be sure that it is a value different from `null`

Comment: Hi faby yes i checked it.  this method also returns null

Comment: so the problem is there.. change it

Comment: this was added by default in the project template. if this needs to change. what would the alternative be then?

Comment: tell me which is your intention, what do you want to get there?

Comment: all i want to do is makesure the signinmanager is not null when the user authentication process takes place. i have added some more code.

Comment: are you able to debug `GetOwinContext` method? check there what is going wrong

Comment: ok it seems like HTTPContext does not have GetOwinContext method at all

Comment: @Sike12: It is an extension method (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270723%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). If not visible add `using System.Web;`...

Comment: Anyone find the cause of this null? I am having the exact same issue?

Comment: I too am having same issue. :( So due to this in the Login controller it errors out stating not initialized.