# No signinmanager class found in Identity 2.1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I just updated all my identity nuget packages so that I can use

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

but VS can't find it. It only finds SingInManager<> with intellisense.
There is no SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(...). I even did a go to definition on SignInManager and looked at the source code in the library and it doesn't show a PasswordSignInAsync with any email parameter, jsut a username. I looked at the version at the top of the file and it shows

> ## region Assembly Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll, v2.0.0.0
>
> C:\TFS\GiftExchange\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.2.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll

So I know I have the correct library right?

[image]

and even that seems to be broken. 
I'm trying to follow the code found here

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/08/05/announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-1-0.aspx

I've updated all my nuget packages and checked them and they all are downloaded with their dependencies downloaded as well. Am I missing something to get SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync?

Comment: please take a look at [using email instead of username in asp.net identity ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758575/asp-net-identity-use-email-instead-of-user-name)

Answer (score 3):

Nothing wrong with packages you have downloaded, actually you can't use it that way.

First create `ApplicationUserManager` class inheriting `UserManager<YourApplicationUser>`

Then create `ApplicationSignInManager` class by inheriting `SignInManager<YourApplicationUser, string>`

Then you can user below code to get owin context for passworSignIn

```
public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            }
            private set 
            { 
                _signInManager = value; 
            }
        }
```

Then you can call

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

Create new project using visual studio using individual accounts template, then you can easily get idea about the `ApplicationUserManager`and ApplicationSignInManager class. Both classes can be found on `IdentityConfig.cs` class under App_Start folder.

Comment: I followed the code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186310/applicationsigninmanager-class-is-null-during-authentication-process, but this gives me a PasswordSignInAsyn where I need to pass in a model.UserName, NOT a email! I want to pass in a email, not a username to sign in like in the original link I posted.

Comment: I just want to log in with email instead of a username, it seems like there should be an easier way to do this??

Comment: Actually identity framework uses username, but you need to use email as your userName if you need to achieve it that way.