# .Net null pointer on SigninManager.ExternalSigninAsync

Tags: .net, google-signin

I'm trying to log a user into my site through Google, and the google login part is working. But when I get the user info back from Google and it goes to my account controller I get the following error:

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 336:            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("loginInfo = " + loginInfo);
Line 337:            // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
Line 338:            var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
Line 339:            switch (result)
Line 340:            {
```

What I'm trying to figure out is what the thing is that's null. It's not `loginInfo` because the debugger in the line before informs me that:

```
loginInfo = Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.ExternalLoginInfo
```

It's also not `SignInManager`, since that's used multiple times throughout the program before with no null pointer errors. And `result` is the new variable being assigned so that can't be null either. What is causing this error?

My whole ExternalLoginCallback method is listed below, though it's just what is automatically made by Google.

```
   //
    // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("loginInfo = " + loginInfo);
        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
        var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
        }
    }
```

Note that others who have a similar problem had it because their Google+ API wasn't turned on, but that's not the case here. Here are the apis I have turned on:

```
BigQuery API    Disable 
Debuglet Controller API     Disable 
Google Cloud SQL    Disable 
Google Cloud Storage    Disable 
Google Cloud Storage JSON API   Disable 
Google+ API     Disable 
Tasks API   Disable 
YouTube Data API v3     Disable
```

**Update:** someone here suggested that one of the properties of loginInfo might be null, but that is also not the case. I expanded the debug statement to list all the properties of the loginInfo and got the following info:

```
loginInfo email = <firstname>.<lastname>@<organization>.org
 external identity = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity
 login = Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserLoginInfo
 Default user name FirstLast
```

**Update 2** After going deeper into the properties of loginInfo I have learned that the ExternalIdentity.Actor property is null, so I think that's the problem, but I still don't know why.

**Update 3** I don't think the Actor being null is the problem because I tried this debug with a different project where the google login works fine and it's also null there. So I still don't know what's going on.

Here are all the properties of loginInfo:

```
loginInfo email = jim.stewart@thelangschool.org
 externalidentity.actor = 
 externalidentity.claims = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity+<get_Claims>d__0
 externalidentity.bootstrapcontext = 
 authenticationtype = ExternalCookie
 loginprovider = Google
 loginkey = 103852334887708800511
 Default user name JimStewart
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. `loginInfo` wasn't the thing that's null, it was `SignInManager`. I never created it in my Startup.auth.cs. If you have this problem, open that file and find the ConfigureAuth method and add this line:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
```

This is actually the same answer as the one in this question: [ApplicationSignInManager class is null during authentication process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186310/applicationsigninmanager-class-is-null-during-authentication-process) . Sorry about the duplicate; I didn't find this one when I was searching for the answer before.