# SignInManager.UserManager = 'SignInManager.UserManager' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, nunit

I'm trying to unit test using nunit framework and I am getting the exception below:

SignInManager = 'SignInManager' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

How can resolve this issue?

Below code throwing exception:

ApplicationUser User = await SignInManager.UserManager.FindByNameAsync   (login.UserName);

if (User != null)  {

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: already I tried above link but it does't work for me

Comment: As the error says: the property SignInManager.UserManager is null. You have to properly initialize it. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186310/applicationsigninmanager-class-is-null-during-authentication-process

Comment: This exception it is coming in when I am working unit testing in normal case it is working fine

Comment: Make sure you initialize ASP.NET Identity properly when unit testing or try to mock the call and return a valid user